# @Autowired in @Service?

Tags: java, spring

I'm having trouble getting @Autowired to work in a class annotated by @Service, the autowired variable always is null. Let me explain:

```
@Service
public class Searcher extends Thread implements ISearcher {
@Autowired
protected ISessionProvider sessionProvider; <-- always null
...
public Searcher() {
sessionProvider.doSomeStuff();
}
```

sessionProvider here is always null.

The strange thing is that the same autowire in a @Controller does work:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER" })
public class SearchController  extends BaseController {
@Autowired
protected ISessionProvider sessionProvider; <-- does work 
@Autowired
protected ISearcher searcher;
```

The last line throws exception because the constructor of Searcher (implementing ISearcher) tries to access sessionProvider, which is null.

I am not sure what i might be doing wrong, it looks like spring doesn't autowire the ISessionProvider in Searcher.

It might be that spring first autowires the Searcher in SearchController, but it should first autowire SessionProvider in Searcher and next autowire Searcher in SearchController. Cause searcher cannot be autowired without a valid SessionProvider. Puzzles my brain ;-)

Can somebody offer a helping brain?

[edit]

- component-scan includes my services, controllers and everything, just checked.
- the I before interfaces is indeed not very nice (old habits)
- not sure if this is a "duplicate" question, mainly because i'm not doing anything with "new", i let do spring do all the hard work, but i'll take a better peek.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: I'll only help if you promise to remove the `I` from the start of your interface names...

Comment: The fact that you're mixing service components and threads suggests your design needs some rework.

Comment: What does your spring configuration look like?

Comment: Are you sure your componant-scan definitions include the package that contains `Searcher` class?

Comment: This isn't a problem with the component-scan definition: Spring would throw an exception while building the context in that case. It looks like a standard case of unmanaged instances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring will first create the bean instance, then inject the beans. You're trying to access to the injected bean when the current bean is created, thus the bean will be `null`. That's default behavior.

If you want/need to execute any logic after creating the bean, use `@PostConstruct` decorated method, which is invoked after the bean has been created and all the dependencies injected. Here's a sample:

```
@Service
public class Searcher extends Thread implements ISearcher {

    @Autowired
    protected ISessionProvider sessionProvider;

    public Searcher() {
        //nothing should be here...
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sessionProvider.doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers all, especially Luiggi and M.Deinum, using @PostConstruct works! Everything is running fine and no more nulls anymore :)

Answer (score 7):

Spring can only do dependeny injection after the bean has been constructed. You are calling the method in the constructor and at that point the `ISessionProvider` hasn't been injected yet and hence it is `null` which in turn leads to a nice `NullPointerException`.

You have 2 solutions

1. Move the code from the constructor to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`
2. Change the default no-arg constructor to take an argument and use that to do dependeny injection instead of the `@Autowired field`.

**Solution 1: move that code to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.**

```
@Service
public class Searcher extends Thread implements ISearcher {
    @Autowired
    protected ISessionProvider sessionProvider;
    ...
    public Searcher() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sessionProvider.doSomeStuff();
    }
```

**Solution 2: Use constructor based dependency injection.**

```
@Service
public class Searcher extends Thread implements ISearcher { 

    protected final ISessionProvider sessionProvider;

    @Autowired
    public Searcher(ISessionProvider sessionProvider) {
        this.sessionProvider=sessionProvider;
        sessionProvider.doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative one using constructor based dependency injection, i just gave it a shot and that also  works nicely. It seems to be a bit cleaner to me compared to the @PostConstruct solution.

Comment: +1 for constructor dependency injection! Makes testing so much easier than the `@PostConstruct` method

Comment: Advantage of constructor based injection is that you cannot (easily) create an invalid object. With `@PostConstruct` and a default constructor you still can create an object without an `ISessionProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do test, but I think the problem is, in class `Searcher`, you created a no-argument constructor, and there you used the "autowired" bean. I guess there you would get NPE. Since spring would instantiate your `Searcher` using default constructor (by reflection) if you didn't specify one, that is, it will use the no-argument constructor you created, but at this moment, the "autowired" bean was not yet injected.

If you want to do something immediately after the bean was instantiated, you can wrap the logic code in a method, and annotate it with `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same issue but i cannot use `@PostConstruct` because i am not using `doinit`. I have a simple method which is getting the language from lang service.
My lang service is `null` here but in another controller it is not `null`, it is getting autowired.

```
@Service
@Configurable(preConstruction = true, autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)  
public class FormSelectLanguageHandler extends SimpleTagSupport {

    @Autowired
    private LangService langService;

    public List<Lang> getLanguages(){
        Sessions session = (Sessions) getJspContext().findAttribute("SHLSESSION");
        List<Lang> languages=new ArrayList<Lang>();
        //List<Lang> allLanguages = langService.findAllLangs();
        List<Lang> all =new ArrayList<Lang>();
        if (isRenderLangLabel()) {
            all = langService.findByDisplayOrderAsc();
        } else {
            all = langService.findByNameOrderByNameAsc();
        }
        Long companyId = (null == session || null == session.getCompany())? null:session.getCompany().getId();
    }
}
```